# Writing to Windows Event Log using win32evtlog from pywin32 library

Tags: windows, python-3.x, events, event-log, pywin32

I have a simple python script that will be running on a windows server, I'd like to log specific events throughout the script to the windows event log. Does anyone have a simple and precise example of writing to the windows event log so I can view the event from the event viewer. I've read through the docs for the pywin32 library and I can't find any clear examples. I've tried building an event using:

```
win32evtlogutil.ReportEvent(ApplicationName, EventID, EventCategory,
                EventType, Inserts, Data, SID)
```

I've had no success, could someone explain the ReportEvent a bit more in depth?

Comment: What do you mean by "*had no success*"? What did you actually try? What was the problem you encountered?

Comment: There's a good example in the `pywin32` base code: https://github.com/mhammond/pywin32/blob/main/win32/Demos/eventLogDemo.py

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A simple example:

> ```py
> >>> import sys
> >>> import time
> >>> import win32evtlog
> >>> import win32evtlogutil
> >>>
> >>>
> >>> "Python {:s} on {:s}".format(sys.version, sys.platform)
> 'Python 3.5.4 (v3.5.4:3f56838, Aug  8 2017, 02:17:05) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32'
> >>>
> >>> DUMMY_EVT_APP_NAME = "Dummy Application"
> >>> DUMMY_EVT_ID = 7040  # Got this from another event
> >>> DUMMY_EVT_CATEG = 9876
> >>> DUMMY_EVT_STRS = ["Dummy event string {:d}".format(item) for item in range(5)]
> >>> DUMMY_EVT_DATA = b"Dummy event data"
> >>>
> >>> "Current time: {:s}".format(time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", time.localtime()))
> 'Current time: 2018-07-18 20:03:08'
> >>>
> >>> win32evtlogutil.ReportEvent(
> ...     DUMMY_EVT_APP_NAME, DUMMY_EVT_ID, eventCategory=DUMMY_EVT_CATEG,
> ...     eventType=win32evtlog.EVENTLOG_WARNING_TYPE, strings=DUMMY_EVT_STRS,
> ...     data=DUMMY_EVT_DATA)
> >>>
> ```

**Output**:

[image: Event Viewer]

You can see the correspondence between the values that I input from code, and the event fields in the (above) image of the *Event Viewer* (*mmc*) window.

*win32evtlogutil.ReportEvent* is part of [[GitHub]: mhammond/pywin32 - Python for Windows (pywin32) Extensions](https://github.com/mhammond/pywin32), which is a *Python* wrapper over *WINAPI*s.
Documentation (*WiP*) can be found at [[GitHub.MHammond]: Python for Win32 Extensions Help](https://mhammond.github.io/pywin32) (or [[ME.TimGolden]: Python for Win32 Extensions Help](http://timgolden.me.uk/pywin32-docs/contents.html)).

Everything you need to know is explained at [[MS.Docs]: ReportEventW function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winbase/nf-winbase-reporteventw), which is the *WINAPI* used to accomplish this task. Make sure to read it carefully (and some other *URL*s that it references) in order to get more familiar about the arguments, what their values could be, and other info.

Make sure not to abuse (tests included), or you might end up getting the event log polluted with lots of garbage data.

Comment: Then would you please mark the answer as a solution, so that it's visible that it solved your problem?

Comment: That's a terrific answer and example except for one thing.  If you're not doing five dummy strings for the event_strings parameter, but a single string instead, it automagically transposes your single string into a boatload of strings, of one character each.  Like "This is a test" becoming "T", "h", "i","s", " ", "i", "s", " ", "a", " ", "t", "e", "s", "t".  So, could you also include a version of that string that's a normal, single string, but that works?  Got it, it's DUMMY_EVT_STRS = [], then DUMMY_EVT_STRS.append(message1), ...

Comment: No, that 's why its name is *DUMMY\_EVT\_STR**S***, or the keyword is *string**s***. User should know that it expects a bunch of strings, even if that bunch only contains a single string. Passing a single string is not respecting the *API* (as the official *URL* also indicates). Also, you don't need 2 lines, but: `DUMMY_EVT_STRS = [message1]`.

Comment: Strings just adds content to Data element in xml. I want to set Name attribute for this element. Can you share any pointers on this? Like something as this ->
 `<Data Name="ProcessID">4</Data>`

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure whether that node is allowed to have attributes. A quick *API* browse, didn't yield positive results.

Comment: @CristiFati Yes, I did scroll through API doc. But I didn't found any leads. If anyone knows if languages other than python able to do this (Which API do they use)? Any lead would be very helpful.

Comment: The language is irrelevant. At the end the all call the same function(s). Anyway your request is odd, seems like an *XY Problem*. Why do you need it exactly like that? As a workaround, you could have the 1st string be the attribute name, the next one its value and then the tag data.