# How to report event to Windows System log in python

Tags: python, windows, pywin32

I am now trying to report event log to windows, right now I am using **win32evtlogutil**

```
        win32evtlogutil.ReportEvent(
            app_name, app_event_id,
            eventCategory=app_event_category,
            eventType=event_type,
            strings=[str(message)], data=app_event_data
        )
```

but this only report event log to application log? but how can I report the event to security log(see picture below)?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of Windows XP SP2+ `ReportEvent()` [cannot be used to report security events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-reporteventa#parameters). You must use the Windows API [`AuthzReportSecurityEvent()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/authz/nf-authz-authzreportsecurityevent) function. PyWin32 [does not have a convenience binding for this function](https://github.com/mhammond/pywin32/issues/1210), so you would need to write the binding yourself.

Comment: can I write it to system log?

Comment: @HongliBu: Yes, use `"System"` as  the 1st argument (*app\_name*) for  *win32evtlogutil.ReportEvent*. Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51385195/writing-to-windows-event-log-using-win32evtlog-from-pywin32-library/51407755#51407755.