# Output of Python script differ depending on way of activation

Tags: python, mysql, multiprocessing, exe

hei guys,

I have an executable python script, say get_data.py (located in project_x/src/) which is working properly, when started by: python get_data.py . It gets data (a list of id's which are necessary for further calculations) from a database via mysql.connector and then processes these data in parallel (via multiprocessing) using pool.map.
BUT it is supposed to be started by an .exe-file (located in project_x/exec/)[EDIT: This .exe uses the php command exec() to directly addresses my python script]. This is not working properly but ending in the try-except-block (in wrapper_fun) when catching the (unknown) mistake and not terminating when deleting the try-except-commands.

Do you have any idea what could be going wrong? I would appreciate any idea. I tried logging but there seems to be a permission problem. My idea is that the connection the db cannot be established and therefore there are no id's.

```
def calculations():
      do_something...

def wrapper_fun(id):
      try:
          calculations(id)
      except Exception:
          return(False)

if __name__ == "__main__":

    import multiprocessing
    import mysql.connector
    from mysql.connector import Error
    host_name = <secret_1>
    user_name = <secret_2>
    passt = <secret_3>
    connection = None
    try:
        connection = mysql.connector.connect(
            host=host_name,
            user=user_name,
            passwd=user_password
        )
    except Error as err:
        print(f"Error: '{err}'")
    d = pd.read_sql_query(query, connection,coerce_float=False)
    connection.close()
    id_s = list(d.ids)
    results = [pool.map(wrapper_fun,id_s)]
         ...
```

Comment: Hey there and welcome to stack overflow. `__name__ == "__main__"` will resolve to `False` if your script is not called directly. See [here](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/whats-in-a-python-s-name-506262fe61e8/)  for a gentle introduction. 

So you should just remove the line `if __name__ == "__main__"` and it should do the trick.

Comment: Hey :) thanks for your quick answer. The .exe calls the python script with the php exec(python get_data.py), so there it is addressed directly.  Furthermore, I added a checkpoint, so I definitely know that the script is being entered. But I will clarify it in my question above :)

Comment: *Always* log your exceptions in your exception handlers instead of just ignoring them silently, unless the handler is for a specific enough exception type it can only possibly be one well-understood thing. After you've added such logs, you'll be in a better place to add clarification to make this question about a narrow, specific, reproducible problem -- as our [mre] guidelines require.

Comment: (if there's a permission problem stopping you from logging, maybe search for a solution to that separately, and come back to this problem after you've fixed it; btw, consider [writing to Windows event log using win32evtlog from pywin32 library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51385195/writing-to-windows-event-log-using-win32evtlog-from-pywin32-library) as a starting place).

Comment: ...I would also suggest that you consider temporarily deleting this question until you're able to get enough information to make the problem reproducible -- if you delete a question yourself, that will stop downvotes and close votes, but let you edit while it's deleted and undelete it later; whereas if it's deleted by a vote or a moderator, it'll take another vote or moderator to reopen it.

Comment: To be clear, there are plenty of ways py2exe can interact badly with multiprocessing, and the problem may be as simple as that (and there are also plenty of ways a parent process can change a child's behavior -- working directory, environment variables, etc), but when you've got a database connector and wonky exception handling and other weirdness going on, it's hard to tell exactly where your problem is of the several possibilities at hand. Part of the point of building a **minimal** reproducer is to isolate a narrow, specific issue, avoiding potential confounding factors.

Comment: (yet another possibility that is if your PHP code is running under a service account, a program it starts can have different permissions from that same program started directly under your own account; so again, there are way too many possible issues here for us to give an answer unless you do some work to narrow things down).